# How to deploy my own package while installation using (npm i)

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to create my own font package (npmjs).

I downloaded all the fonts and created a CSS script to import them easily.

But I don't understand what is the best way to deploy them in the parent/target package while installing (`npm i my-package`).

Is it possible? If yes, how to do it? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score -2):

if **name** == "**main**":
code outside of a class or function goes here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).